# Autolayout conflicts autorotation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I add a view in storyboard using autolayout.  I set the constraints on the view so there is no problem for the view with autorotation.

Now, I add a subview to the view programmingly instead of using stroyboard.  The autorotation doesn't work now.  The subview always show as portrait, the same thing as you don't set constraints on a view in storyboard.  I set the autoresizingMask = ~UIViewAutoresizingNone; but it doesn't work since this is for old style of sprint and struct.

Is there an easy way to do to make autorotation work for a view programmingly adds to a view which is using storyboard?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;` to your's programmaticaly created view.
2. Programmaticaly add constraints for it.

Comment: If you keep ivar references to the constraints, you can even change the `constant` value during the rotation to place this view in a different places - one place for portrait, the other for landscape.

Comment: @Cy the first choice to set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is still doesn't work

Comment: @user2543991, you need both.